# Grails install error "java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase not present"

Tags: grails, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-httpclient

I am getting TypeNotPresentException in my grails application. The Stacktrace snippet is below

```
[INFO]   [groovyc] java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase not present
[INFO]   [groovyc]  at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:98)
[INFO]   [groovyc]  at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:107)
[INFO]   [groovyc]  at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:31)
[INFO]   [groovyc]  at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.WildcardTypeImpl.getUpperBounds(WildcardTypeImpl.java:112)
[INFO]   [groovyc]  at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v5.Java5.configureWildcardType(Java5.java:122)
[INFO]   [groovyc]  at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v5.Java5.configureType(Java5.java:85)
[INFO]   [groovyc]  at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v5.Java5.configureTypeArguments(Java5.java:154)
[INFO]   [groovyc]  at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v5.Java5.configureParameterizedType(Java5.java:134)
[INFO]   [groovyc]  at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v5.Java5.configureType(Java5.java:87)
[INFO]   [groovyc]  at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v5.Java5.makeClassNode(Java5.java:374)
[INFO]   [groovyc]  at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v5.Java5.configureClassNode(Java5.java:315)
[INFO]   [groovyc]  at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.lazyClassInit(ClassNode.java:263)
[INFO]   [groovyc]  at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.getInterfaces(ClassNode.java:341)
[INFO]   [groovyc]  at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.declaresInterface(ClassNode.java:929)
[INFO]   [groovyc]  at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.implementsInterface(ClassNode.java:909)
[INFO]   [groovyc]  at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.isDerivedFromGroovyObject(ClassNode.java:899)
[INFO]   [groovyc]  at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.isGroovyObject(AsmClassGenerator.java:2741)
[INFO]   [groovyc]  at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitPropertyExpression(AsmClassGenerator.java:2717)
[INFO]   [groovyc]  at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.PropertyExpression.visit(PropertyExpression.java:55)
[INFO]   [groovyc]  at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitAndAutoboxBoolean(AsmClassGenerator.java:4111)
[INFO]   [groovyc]  at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.makeCallSite(AsmClassGenerator.java:2171)
[INFO]   [groovyc]  at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.makeCall(AsmClassGenerator.java:2008)
[INFO]   [groovyc]  at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.makeCall(AsmClassGenerator.java:1994)
[INFO]   [groovyc]  at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitStaticMethodCallExpression(AsmClassGenerator.java:2404)
[INFO]   [groovyc]  at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.StaticMethodCallExpression.visit(StaticMethodCallExpression.java:43)
[INFO]   [groovyc]  at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitAndAutoboxBoolean(AsmClassGenerator.java:4111)
[INFO]   [groovyc]  at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.evaluateExpression(AsmClassGenerator.java:1437)
[INFO]   [groovyc]  at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitReturnStatement(AsmClassGenerator.java:1398)
[INFO]   [groovyc]  at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ReturnStatement.visit(ReturnStatement.java:47)
[INFO]   [groovyc]  at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.CodeVisitorSupport.visitBlockStatement(CodeVisitorSupport.java:35)
```

My buildconfig.groovy file has the following code

```
dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes eg.
        //      compile('com.cm:admanager:1.4.8') {
        //          transitive = false
        //      }

        compile('org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.5.0') {
            excludes 'httpclient', 'groovy', 'nekohtml', 'ezmorph', 'commons-logging'
        }
        compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1') {
            excludes 'commons-logging'
        }
        compile('org.perf4j:perf4j:0.9.16')
        compile('com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:1.4.4')
        compile('com.google.guava:guava:16.0.1')
        test('org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3')
    }
```

.sh file being used to run the project

```
rm -rf "$HOME/.ivy2/cache/com.cm/nci-autodata"
rm -rf "$HOME/.m2/repository/com/cm/nci-autodata"

mvn -f build.xml -Pdev -X clean install
```

httpclient-4.0.1 is supposed to have the required class but it still gives me this exception. I checked my .ivy2 folder and it has the required jar file in the correct place. Any idea what's going on here?

This is the project I was given at my new job. I have not written this code and the person who did has left the company.

Thanks

Comment: what version of grails? how are you running it?

Comment: 1.3.7. I am including the .sh file above that i am using to run the project

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it. I had to delete the .grails and .ivy2 folder and recompile again. It downloaded all the correct dependencies and worked. Thanks a lot for help guys